# How to pass an argument name instead of a string when using a while loop

Tags: swift, swift3

[My Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wqPF.png)

Hello ! I've been searching for an answer as im sure it is often encountered be programming newbies but I couldnt find an answer .
 The question is how to pass an adress to my a1,a2,a3 argument in the append() brackets. Everything i came up with in the end formed a string and I couldnt find any functions in the scroll pop ups which could help me achieve my goal. I was actually surprised because i thought simply typing the name in this form "a"+String(index) or something similiar will work just fine but I quickly understood why its not acceptable.
  Of course i could do this manually as its only 3 arguments to append to an Array but where is the fun in that ?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately it's not clear what you are trying to do here. Firstly, post your code not a picture of it then described clearly what you want to happen - also explain what you have tried and why this is not working, do you get any errors?

Comment: First of all, post code not images. Second of all it's unclear what you're asking. Add also an example what the expected result is.

Comment: what's your question? Any code snippet of what you have implemented?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use contentsOf: collection

```
var array: [String] = [String]()

array.append(contentsOf: [a1,a2,a3])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem the way I wanted to but is still way smoother than 

       dataURL.append(a1)
        dataURL.append(a2)
        dataURL.append(a3)
thank you very much !